# From what LEGO set is this plastic bag of parts?

Tags: set-identification

[image]Please help to identify this plastic bag of LEGO parts.

Answer (score 26):

This is [Hidden Side Newbury Haunted High School 70425](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70425-1#T=P)

[image]

Found looking for [Plant Stem, Curved with 2 Thorns and 2 Swirls in Trans-Neon Green](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=28870&in=S) on Bricklink (only one with more than 3)

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Thanks for answering the question and explaining how you figured it out.  This is great.

Comment: I'm just so stunned and impressed by what just happened here.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any of the 6x6 light blue ("medium azure"?) plates listed in that kit (https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70425-1) that obviously appear in the lower left section of the bag in the OP picture.  Or is that just a problem with lighting/coloring in the OP picture?

Comment: @CitizenRon that plate looks like light bluish gray to me, which does appear in the parts list